# Manjaro Update fails: signature is unknown trust

Tags: upgrade, gpg, manjaro, pacman

I was installing Manjaro GNOME 18.0.4 for my sister. However, when I tried to update all packages using `pacman -Syu`, the update fails due to two signature errors:

- `dunst` package with signature by `"Matti Hyttinen <matti@manjaro.org>"`
- `notification-daemon` with signature by `"Brett Cornwall <brett@i--b.com>"`

Interestingly, there wasn't even anything I could have messed up, as this was the first thing I did after installation (and I reinstalled Manjaro, as it could have been a problem in installation). Additionally, it appears that both problematic packages are for notifications.

I - of course - already tried to look up the problem, and the solution I found over and over was

```
rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro
pacman-key --refresh-keys
```

as root. But this solution does not work at all in this case.

Full error message (Same with `dunst`):

```
$ sudo pacman -S notification-daemon
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) notification-daemon-3.20.0-3

Total Download Size:   0.05 MiB
Total Installed Size:  0.74 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 notification-daemon...    52.4 KiB  64.7K/s 00:01 [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
error: notification-daemon: signature from "Brett Cornwall <brett@i--b.com>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/notification-daemon-3.20.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] 
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Edit: I changed all `SigLevel` options (4 in total) in `/etc/pacman.conf` to `SigLevel = Never`, ran `pacman -Syu` and changed `SigLevel` options back. The system is now up-to-date, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Does this [Manjaro forum post](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/update-invalid-or-corrupted-package/76556/3) help?

Comment: It does, apparently, and I don't know why I did not find this post myself. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the "solution" section as an answer and remove it from the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solution:

- open `/etc/pacman.conf`
- change all `SigLevel` entries to `Never` (comment the old ones out)
- `pacman -Syu`
- change `/etc/pacman.conf` back
- `rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg`
- `pacman-key --init`
- `pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro`
- `pacman-key --refresh-keys`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when the system was not updated for too long.
Seems like some new keys were added since than and my "archlinux-keyring" package is way too old for this.

Here is what I had to do to fix it:

```
pacman-key --populate archlinux
pacman -S archlinux-keyring
```